# Having Trouble With Python Dictionary Manipulation

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code here that works when I use separate if statements for each ingredient, but fails when using a for loop to edit the values in the dictionary. I cannot seem to figure out why my report screen does not change after entering a drink order or seems to go negative when checking resources after entering in multiple drink orders). It is a virtual coffee machine. The problematic code is near the end in the for loop and in the check resources function. I tried debugging without success. Here is the code:

```
MENU = {
    "espresso": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 50,
            "milk": 0,
            "coffee": 18,
        },
        "cost": 1.50,
    },
    "latte": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 200,
            "milk": 150,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 2.50,
    },
    "cappuccino": {
        "ingredients": {
            "water": 250,
            "milk": 100,
            "coffee": 24,
        },
        "cost": 3.00,
    }
}

resources = {
    "water": 100,
    "milk": 0,
    "coffee": 18,
}


water = resources["water"]
milk = resources["milk"]
coffee = resources["coffee"]
money_profit = 0


# TODO 1. Create a report of how much water, milk, coffee, and money you have used
def report(water_ingredient, milk_ingredient, coffee_ingredient, money_in_box):
    print("The coffee machine has:")
    print(f"Water: {water_ingredient}ml")
    print(f"Milk: {milk_ingredient}ml")
    print(f"Coffee: {coffee_ingredient}g")
    print(f"Money: ${format(money_in_box, '.2f')}")


# TODO 2. Check if resources are available for coffee order
def check_resources(ingredients):
    for item in ingredients:
        if resources[item] < ingredients[item]:
            print(f"Sorry, not enough {item}!")
            return False
    return True


def money(user_choice):
    global money_profit
    print(f"The cost of {user_choice} is ${format(MENU[user_choice]['cost'], '.2f')}.\n Please insert coins: ")
    quarters = int(input("How many quarters?: "))
    dimes = int(input("How many dimes?: "))
    nickels = int(input("How many nickels?: "))
    pennies = int(input("How many pennies?: "))
    money_total = (quarters * .25) + (dimes * .10) + (nickels * .05) + (pennies * .01)
    if money_total < MENU[user_choice]['cost']:
        print(f"Sorry, not enough money! Here is your change: ${format(money_total, '.2f')}.")
        return False
    money_profit += MENU[user_choice]['cost']
    money_total -= MENU[user_choice]['cost']
    print(f"I have enough resources, enjoy your {user_choice}!")
    print(f"Here is ${format(money_total, '.2f')} in change.")
    return True


# TODO 3. Create user input explaining which coffee you would like to order: "Espresso/Latte/Cappuccino"
coffee_machine = True

while coffee_machine:
    user_input = input("What kind of coffee would you like to order? (Espresso/Latte/Cappuccino): ").lower().strip()

    if user_input == "report":
        report(water, milk, coffee, money_profit)

    elif user_input == "off":
        coffee_machine = False
        print("Goodbye!")

    elif user_input in ("espresso", "latte", "cappuccino"):
        if check_resources(MENU[user_input]['ingredients']):
            # TODO 4. When user selects order, ask user to insert money
            total_money = money(user_input)
            # TODO 5. Checks to make sure a drink was actually made
            if total_money:
                for item in MENU[user_input]['ingredients']:
                    resources[item] -= MENU[user_input]['ingredients'][item]
    else:
        print("Invalid selection.")
```

Comment: I ran the code and it works, I even set all the resources to 1000. Can you post the choices you gave to the machine, so to pinpoint what is wrong?

Comment: It was mainly the report function kept repeating the same values. A couple of times as well, it was giving me negative resources in the report but that might be an earlier version before I posted here. It was after I ran through espresso a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the initial water, milk, and coffee variables were the issue. Still don't understand why, but I removed them and changed up the report function to directly call them. It seemed to fix the other bug as well.

```
from main import MENU, resources

# TODO 1. Create a report of how much water, milk, coffee, and money you have used
def report(water_ingredient, milk_ingredient, coffee_ingredient, money_in_box):
    print("The coffee machine has:")
    print(f"Water: {water_ingredient}ml")
    print(f"Milk: {milk_ingredient}ml")
    print(f"Coffee: {coffee_ingredient}g")
    print(f"Money: ${format(money_in_box, '.2f')}")


# TODO 2. Check if resources are available for coffee order
def check_resources(ingredients):
    for item in ingredients:
        if resources[item] < ingredients[item]:
            print(f"Sorry, not enough {item}!")
            return False
    return True


def money(user_choice):
    global money_profit
    print(f"The cost of {user_choice} is ${format(MENU[user_choice]['cost'], '.2f')}.\n Please insert coins: ")
    quarters = int(input("How many quarters?: "))
    dimes = int(input("How many dimes?: "))
    nickels = int(input("How many nickels?: "))
    pennies = int(input("How many pennies?: "))
    money_total = (quarters * .25) + (dimes * .10) + (nickels * .05) + (pennies * .01)
    if money_total < MENU[user_choice]['cost']:
        print(f"Sorry, not enough money! Here is your change: ${format(money_total, '.2f')}.")
        return False
    money_profit += MENU[user_choice]['cost']
    money_total -= MENU[user_choice]['cost']
    print(f"I have enough resources, enjoy your {user_choice}!")
    print(f"Here is ${format(money_total, '.2f')} in change.")
    return True


# TODO 3. Create user input explaining which coffee you would like to order: "Espresso/Latte/Cappuccino"
coffee_machine = True

money_profit = 0

while coffee_machine:
    user_input = input("What kind of coffee would you like to order? (Espresso/Latte/Cappuccino): ").lower().strip()

    if user_input == "report":
        report(resources["water"], resources["milk"], resources["coffee"], money_profit)

    elif user_input == "off":
        coffee_machine = False
        print("Goodbye!")

    elif user_input in ("espresso", "latte", "cappuccino"):
        if check_resources(MENU[user_input]['ingredients']):
            # TODO 4. When user selects order, ask user to insert money
            total_money = money(user_input)
            # TODO 5. Checks to make sure a drink was actually made
            if total_money:
                for item in MENU[user_input]['ingredients']:
                    resources[item] -= MENU[user_input]['ingredients'][item]
    else:
        print("Invalid selection.")
```